# Refreshing files without killall Finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I would like to have a file list refresh in a Folder (like after switching between YES/NO in hidden files option). The only way I found is `killall Finder` which is fine, but it causes the screen to blinks for a sec (as the Finder is restarting).

Is there a way to refresh the Finder file list without actually killing it?

Comment: What OS? It was possible at Mavericks, but not since El Cap, afaik. HS might respond to cmd/shift/. [period] as that will toggle invisibles without needing a script, but it's an issue i haven't suffered in a long time, so can't test its effectiveness.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm on HS, but would like it to work on Mojave as well and probably on Sierra too (need this for internal thing in a company and we do not have the latest macOS on every mac).

Comment: Probably needs a bit of updating to cover that it's script-free in HS [edit... ahh, already covered by 2nd answer] , but see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168540/show-hide-hidden-files-without-restarting-finder/168544

Comment: I discovered this whilst looking for something else entirely - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49546/85275

Answer (score 1):

This particular use hadn't occurred to me.  I have finder set to always show all my files.  However sometimes when a new file is created it doesn't show up. Switching to another directory and switching back seems to work.  E.g. Switch to the parent, or a sibling directory, then back to your starting one.  Two clicks.  Much faster than relaunching Finder.